# get the SUM of each Person by the PersonID

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following columns in a table:

```
SCORE_ID 
SCORE_PERSON_ID 
SCORE_VOTE
```

The SCORE_PERSON_ID is a variable. I need to sum the SCORE_VOTE per SCORE_PERSON_ID.

Can you suggest of a good way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function like `count` or `sum`

```
SELECT SCORE_PERSON_ID, sum(SCORE_VOTE) as score
FROM table 
GROUP BY `SCORE_PERSON_ID`
```

Answer (score 2):

I think either this is what you're asking for:

```
SELECT SUM(SCORE_VOTE)
  FROM <your_table_name>
 WHERE SCORE_PERSON_ID = <some value>
```

or this:

```
SELECT SUM(SCORE_VOTE)
  FROM <your_table_name>
 GROUP BY SCORE_PERSON_ID
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: if you use ' WHERE SCORE_PERSON_ID = <some value>' and 'GROUP BY SCORE_PERSON_ID' together like this its kind of redundant

Comment: Good point.  I had two ideas in my head and combined them, for some strange reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(SCORE_VOTE)
FROM SCORES
GROUP BY SCORE_PERSON_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
select sum(SCORE_VOTE) as score  from TABLE group by SCORE_PERSON_ID
```

this is sum them up for each person

```
select sum(SCORE_VOTE)  as score  from TABLE where SCORE_PERSON_ID = 1
```